# sitemesh page exclusion

Tags: java, sitemesh

I'd like to exclude a set of pages from decoration (using sitemesh 2 and spring-mvc 3.1). Here is my decorators.xml:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
    <excludes>
        <pattern>/WEB-INF/view/data/tabs</pattern>
    </excludes>
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jspx">
        <pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</pattern>
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

And then in my page I'm using jquery-ui tabs with ajax loaded pages, as described here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax. So obviously I don't want the content in the tabs decorated again! I've tried putting the pattern as `/WEB-INF/view/data/tabs/*` in addition to what's listed above, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.xml is the main properties file that gets read by the container whne launching your webapp.
It will take the interception point as a start point to your application, so every definition you make realted to your files start at this point as relative path.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by providing the absolute path, e.g. `/spring/data/tabs/*`, (web.xml is intercepting `/spring/*` and sending to DispatcherServlet).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,and I solved is by this way that adding a new decorator named "no":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/layouts/">
    <excludes>
        <pattern>/static/*</pattern>
        <pattern>/api/*</pattern>
        <pattern>/</pattern>
    </excludes>
    <decorator name="default" page="default.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="no" page=""></decorator>
</decorators>
```

and add the meta to your page that does not want to use decorator:

```
<meta name="decorator" content="no" />
```

Comment: is this the best way @v11 ?

Comment: not sure whether it's best way. but it works for me.

Comment: Yes ! Its working perfectly.. Let us see if anybody asnwer